# Unable to locate cyclic dependency for compileTestGroovy Gradle Build

Tags: java, spring, gradle, groovy, spock

I'm receiving a stackOverflowError for the compileTestGroovy task Gradle (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_plugin.html).  Error with the stacktrace:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

compileGroovy and the other tasks part of Gradle's Groovy plugin *build just fine*.  This is occurring only for the test tasks.  I believe this is a cyclic dependency but I've excluded all dependencies for testImplementations and I am unsure what the cause might be.

[Here is the full build gradle file](https://gist.github.com/SriVadrevu/b6d3e78da2620fa03ffb55487ea1d1cc)

And here are my test dependencies, there are only 2:

```
testImplementation ("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28") {
    transitive = false
  }
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M5-groovy-3.0') {
    transitive = false
}
```

A pointer in the direction of what the issue might be (if not a cyclic dependency) would also be very helpful.

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, I can.  Here is the [full build gradle file](https://gist.github.com/SriVadrevu/b6d3e78da2620fa03ffb55487ea1d1cc).

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same issue.  Our CI jobs that execute tests have been running years without this issue and then one day a couple of weeks ago it started happening.  I thought it may have been a cyclic dependency at first, but now I'm not sure.

What ended up working was putting this in the build.gradle file (emphasis on the 'Xss' configuration):

```
compileTestGroovy {
  configure(groovyOptions.forkOptions) {
    memoryMaximumSize = '3g'
    jvmArgs = ['-Xms1g', '-Xmx3g', '-Xss4M']
  }
}
```

I set Xss to '1M' first and that didn't resolve the issue.  I bumped it to '4M' and had no more issues.

I'll put down my discovery process of coming to this solution here and hopefully someone more knowledgeable can tell me if I'm right.

I first had to learn what the StackOverflowError is and the difference between 'heap' vs 'stack' using the following:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/diagnosing-javalangstackoverflowerror
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYAyEQEcTVI (the whole video was great, but the first 10 minutes was very helpful in differentiating stack vs heap)

Based on that, I know our teams use Spock and some homegrown testing frameworks to create the tests that are causing the issue.  There are ALOT of Spock data tables and static variables used throughout thousands of tests.

Maybe we just finally reached critical mass after another test was added using static variables and data tables (which I think are stored in stack??) and then that started tripping this error?