# Unable to find cyclic dependency for failing CompileTestGroovy gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, stack-overflow, spock

I keep receiving a stackOverflowError for my compileTestGroovy task in Gradle.  Error with the stacktrace:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

compileGroovy and the other tasks part of Gradle's Groovy plugin *build just fine*.  This is occurring only for the test tasks.

Originally I believed this was a cyclic dependency so I've excluded all dependencies for testImplementations and it still fails--I am unsure what the cause might be.

[Here is the full build gradle file](https://gist.github.com/SriVadrevu/b6d3e78da2620fa03ffb55487ea1d1cc)

And here are my test dependencies, there are only 2.  Transitive excludes all dependencies for those packages:

```
testImplementation ("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.28") {
    transitive = false
  }
testImplementation('org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M5-groovy-3.0') {
    transitive = false
}
```

A pointer in the direction of what the issue might be (if not a cyclic dependency) would also be very helpful.

Comment: Could you provide any more lines of the exception?

Comment: Please don't post twice: [Unable to locate cyclic dependency for compileTestGroovy Gradle Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101298/unable-to-locate-cyclic-dependency-for-compiletestgroovy-gradle-build)